# Why does selenium cant install it on my mac?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to use selenium on my mac book pro. However, I can't import it. I have already un- and re-installed it.

> Error Code:Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in 
> import selenium
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks. I will remember that. I have removed and updated my previous comment.

Comment: Did you any error message in the installation process? A text log would be nice to see. Did you install it with pip (i.e `pip install -U selenium`)?

Comment: Is your file named as "selenium.py"? It may cause some problems

Comment: @ grayrigel Ive tryt it but no error code

Comment: Run `pip3 list` (or `pip` if you're using python2) and see whether Selenium shows up in that list. If it doesn't it, your pip command didn't go thru correctly.